# How can I use ngnix to redirect to multiple subdomains and show error pages?

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, server

I am having trouble satisfying *all* of the following conditions in `nginx`:

1. When visting root, i.e., `/`, redirect to `/blog`.
2. When visiting `/app`, stay at `/app`.
3. When visiting anything else, e.g., `/fake/directory`, show the *404 page*.

Usually some combination of two of these will work, but not the third.

I have tried `try_files` with different `location`s in a certain order, `return`, and `rewrite` in various combinations, but I'm missing some detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the follow will work:

```
location = / {
  rewrite / /blog;
}

location ~ /blog.* {
  # desired options, php, index, etc.
}

location /app {
  # desired options, php, index, etc.
}

location / {
  return 404;
}
```

Explanation:

- if nginx found `=`, it terminates - so the `/` is OK
- `blog` and `apps` locations are simple (I think)
- `location /`: it's prefix. `nginx` will try find the longest match. The `/blog` and `/app` are longest than `/`. The `/fake/directory` will match only the last `location /`, so will `return 404`.

More information see [`nginx location`'s documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)